# The parameter is incorrect (WinMgmt)

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk

I have a BizTalk 2013r2 Standard Edition application server with CU7 installed. The BizTalk databases are hosted on a separate Sql Server 2014 server. This setup has been working fine for many months - until today! A colleague used the BizTalk admin console to make a change to the address BizTalk uses to the reach the SMTP server, by selecting Platform Settings\Adapters\SMTP\\properties.
After making this change, on attempting to refresh the BizTalk Admin Console, the following error is displayed:

[image: TheParameterIsIncorrect]

From what I've googled, it seems this may be due to some corruption in the SSO database. I have a backup of the SSO database, and a backup of the SSO key along with the password. Before restoring the backup of the SSO database, I wanted to check that I would be able to restore the key, so I ran ssoconfig -restoreSecret from the command line. I was prompted to enter the password. If I intentionally enter the wrong password then it tells me the password is incorrect. However, if I enter the correct password then it displays the message "BAD DATA".

Although the BizTalk admin console is currently unusable, thankfully the BizTalk host instance continue to run and messages are being processed as expected.

Can anyone please suggest why I'm getting the "BAD DATA" message, or perhaps a work-around in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem again and blogged about it at [BizTalk WinMgt error solution](https://www.connected-pawns.com/2018/01/10/biztalk-winmgt-error-solution/). As Colin says the hard part is identifying the corrupt handler. It is probably the SMTP send handler but you should check this using WBEMTEST first. I found this link helpful on using WBEMTest.  [The parameter is incorrect (WinMgt)" error when refreshing the BizTalk Group in BizTalk Administration Console](http://biztalksupport.blogspot.co.nz/2016/11/the-parameter-is-incorrect-winmgt-error.html)

In my case a quick fix to bring the BizTalk Administration Console back to life was to hack the database. N.B. This probably won't be supported by MS. In my case it was the FTP send handler that screwed up. So I ran

```
USE [BizTalkMgmtDb]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[adm_SendHandler2_Delete]
        @AdapterName = N'FTP',
        @HostName = N'Sending32'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

At this point the BizTalk Administration console came back to life. In my case it worked because I was creating a new handler but in your case you just edited it. It will take all your SMTP handling out.

I then fixed the corruption using the BizTalk Administration console.
In my case I had to set every FTP receive and send adapter temporarily to a FILE adapter.

I then deleted the FTP adapter and then re-added it. Finally I reset the all the change receive and send location from FILE back to FTP.

This was all very scary on a live system.

Finally I believe that this is bug in BizTalk 2013 R2 because I've seen it happen on 2 systems and now I have heard that the same thing happened to you.

Comment: I was able to fix by following the guidance on Mark's blog.

Answer (score 1):

The WinMgt error happens when one of the Adapters setting has gotten itself corrupted.  See [WinMgt error when refreshing Group Hub](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ddc32037-b449-4ed8-903a-99fc69986ede/winmgt-error-when-refreshing-group-hub?forum=biztalkgeneral)

Removing and re-adding the adapter to the host usually fixes it.  The trick of course is identifying which Adapter / Host, I would start with the SMTP adapter in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Colin but I don’t think I can navigate to remove the adapter through the UI - it crashes before I get chance. I will check this in the morning.

Comment: Actually Colin, you were correct it was possible to delete the adapter, I just had to work around the error dialogs.